# In IntelliJ, which Java Compiler should be chosen for Flex-AS3 modules?

Tags: eclipse, macos, intellij-idea

Hi
Can someone tell me which Java Compiler should be chosen for Flex-AS3 modules in OSX?
Javac
Jikes
Eclipse
or
Javac-in-process ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't matter. Compiling Flex modules does not use the Java compiler, so the value of this setting has no effect for Flex modules.